# How to step-into kubernetes source code using IDE?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to run kubectl commands and see the run-time execution using an IDE like GoLand for example?

I would like to open 'apply.go' source code and see how the code is executed when I type: kubectl apply -f/hit Enter step-by-step.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to do such a thing? Isn't kubectl more or less an HTTP client that sends requests to the K8s API Server, with all the clever K8s things happening server side?

Comment: I am interested in the underlying engineering of such a simple yet complex operation. Also I wanted to observe the subtle differences between the imperative vs declarative approach; create vs apply and see the kind of steps each use to come up with almost identical results. The documentation is great and well understood, I just want to see what's happening.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Go does offer a debugger, Delve. But I don’t think this will be very helpful. Kubectl code is kind of hard to understand even if you already know it and kubectl apply is the single most complex thing in all of kubectl. So complex that the logic is being moved to the server side, in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

- Lens is the best IDE for kubernetes that I have used upto now.
- It serves everything in a plate , as there is no need to mug up the commands of kubectl,
  you can make changes in any of kubernetes yaml file from lens and it will apply changes in to your cluster.
- install lens for your OS: https://github.com/lensapp/lens/releases/
- you can know more about lens from this link : https://github.com/lensapp/lens/